# LSTM RNN always predict the same class

Tags: neural-networks, classification, lstm, keras

I have following code

```
model_rnn = Sequential()
model_rnn.add(SimpleRNN(128, input_shape=(t,X_train_rnn.shape[2],)))
model_rnn.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_rnn.add(LSTM(128))
model_rnn.add(Dropout(0.3))
model_rnn.add(Dense(3, activation="softmax"))
  
opt= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
model_rnn.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = opt,  metrics = ["accuracy"])
history_rnn = model_rnn.fit(X_train_rnn,y_train_rnn, epochs=50, batch_size = 16, validation_data= (X_test_rnn, y_test_rnn))
```

I wanted to classify some financial data from 10 years into 3 classes, but I always get the same class with RNN. I tried different number of epochs, batch_size, learning rate, simpler and complexer model, but nothing worked.

I have in the training data about 2000 observations and about 800 in the test data. My classes are balanced. Does anyone have any idea what I could change?

Comment: The code you’re using has SimpleRNN, not an LSTM, as stated in your title. // What happens if you remove dropout?

Comment: Sorry, I entered one of the options that I tried, but at the end I would like to include LSTM. Now, I tried not to include dropout but nothing changed. I forgot to mention that I have tried StandardScaler and MinMax scaling with range (0,1) and (-1,1) but no big differences.

Comment: I don't know if this is affecting you, it depends on your workflow, but a common cause of this is forgetting to scale the input (X) before passing to the network. For example, did you standardize the features for training?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried different methods, and with ususal feedforward neural network everything works fine, but the problem is with RNN and LSTM. I am not sure what can I do additionally. `scaler = MinMaxScaler (feature_range = (-1,1))  
scaler.fit(X_train) 
X_train_, X_test_ = scaler.transform(X_train), scaler.transform(X_test)` . I hope that this is the correct way of the transformation. I have tried also Standard Scaler and range (0,1) for MinMax.